Cardinality/measure of the irrationals?
I was reading this reply to real analysis - Measure of the irrational numbers?
While reading up on Real Analysis recently, I have been having all the same doubts described in the above question. For completeness, here they are

I have read that the measure of the irrational numbers on an interval $[a,b]=b−a$
. This both makes sense and doesn't make sense to me. If you consider that the union of the irrationals with the rationals are the reals, then if the rationals have measure $0$, then the irrationals must have the same measure as the reals. (right?)
But if you consider that the irrationals are totally disconnected, then it is a collection of disconnected points. If it's a collection of disconnected points, like the rationals, how can it have a non-zero measure?
Another fact I'm not sold on, which may be the source of the problem, is that there isn't a bijection between the rationals and the irrationals. If both of these sets are totally disconnected by each other and both dense, that is, "Between any $\forall a,b\in\mathbf{R}$, such that $a<b$, there is exists an irrational $i$ and a rational $q$ satisfying $a<i<b$, and $a<q<b$."

And the linked answer says

[...] however there is not only one irrational between [any] two rationals, and not only one rational between [any] two irrationals. Rather there are countably many rationals between two irrationals, but uncountably many irrationals between two rationals.

Well, how is that possible if $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ defined below is discontinuous everywhere? $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in\mathbf{Q}\\0,&x\notin\mathbf{Q}\end{cases}$$
What am I missing here about continuity and countability?
Further in the answer @celtschk says

Maybe it helps if instead of the rationals, you consider the numbers with finite decimal expansion, which also is a countable dense subset. Here, it might be more intuitive that, you have many more possibilities for numbers if you can arbitrarily continue your number string infinitely than if you are forced to stop after finitely many digits. Yet again, between any two finite-expansion numbers, you always can find an infinite-expansion number (just add infinitely many non-zero digits to the smaller one, after first padding it to the length of the larger with zeroes if necessary), and between any two infinite-expansion numbers you can find a finite-expansion number (just cut the larger one at an appropriate point).

Which is also unclear to me due to a few things.

I do not know what exactly numbers with finite decimal expansion means?
I do not understand why they are a countable dense subset?
"[...] between any two infinite-expansion numbers you can find a finite-expansion number (just cut the larger one at an appropriate point)." This statement doesn't make sense. If you can truncate at any point, however large, isn't that the same as infinite-expansion?

I am adding this as a separate question because this is a great answer to all my doubts, but needs substantial clarification for me. And because the answer was last edited four years ago.

What you are missing about continuity and countability seems to be that they are not that closely related.  Both the rationals and the irrationals are dense subsets of the reals.  Between any two real numbers, be they rational or irrational, there are infinitely many irrationals and infinitely many irrationals.  And this says nothing about the possibility of a one-to-one correspondence between those sets.  As to your numbered questions:

A finite decimal expansion is something like $314.1516$ or $-0.23$.  An optional $-$ sign, then finitely many digits, then a decimal point, and then finitely many digits.
They are a countable set because you can list them: e.g. first those with one digit, then those with two digits, then three, etc.  They are a dense set because any interval $(a,b)$ with $a < b$ contains points of this set.
For example, let's say your two numbers are $\pi$ and $\pi + 1/10^6$.
$\pi$ happens to be an infinite-expansion number, whose expansion starts
$3.14159265...$, and so is $\pi + 1/10^6$, whose expansion starts $3.14159365...$.  An example of a finite-expansion number between them is $3.141593$.


To answer your specific questions:

The numbers with finite decimal expansion are the ones which are some integer divided by a power of 10. When written out in decimal, it only continues a finite number of places after the decimal point. For instance, $\frac{1}{2} = 0.5$, $\frac{3}{20} = 0.15$ have finite decimal expansion. $\frac{1}{3} = 0.333\dots$ and $\sqrt{2} = 1.41421\dots$ do not.
They are dense because between any two real numbers you can find a number with finite decimal expansion. Suppose we have two real numbers $a<b$. Since they are different, their decimal expansions aren't the same, so they have to disagree at some point. Suppose $a = n.d_1d_2d_3\dots d_kd_{k+1}\dots$ and $b = n.d_1d_2d_3\dots d_kd'_{k+1}\dots$ where $n$ is an integer (let's assume positive) and the $d_i$ are decimal digits. Then $c = n.d_1d_2d_3\dots d_kd'_{k+1}$ is a number whose decimal expansion is finite. It is larger than $a$ and smaller than $b$.
I'm not exactly sure what you mean here. Given an infinite decimal expansion, you can cut it off at any point. However, any individual cut-off value will only be an approximations to the infinite expansion.


So with this taken into account, let's go back to the function $f$ you defined. I'll go back to using the rationals as well.
The definition of continuity is that at any point $x_0$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. What this means in words is that as we get closer and closer to point $x_0$, the values of $f$ get closer and closer to $f(x_0)$.
But this is not the case! For any rational or irrational point $x_0$, as we get close to $x_0$, there are both rational values ($f(x) = 1$) and irrational values ($f(x)=0$), so we aren't continuous.

A way to break the seeming symmetry between the rationals and the irrationals is the Thomae function (see here). Without going into too many details, it's a function which is continuous at every irrational and discontinuous at every rational. You can see why in the article using the definition of continuity.
However, there is no "reverse-Thomae" function which is continuous at the rationals and discontinuous at the irrationals. The reasoning for this is rather complicated, though, but it boils down to the fact that the rationals can be counted and the irrationals cannot.

Just to add to your "reverse-Thomae" function comment, the precise issue with there being no such function is that the set of points of continuity of a function forms a $G_\delta$ set, and the rationals are not a $G_\delta$ set. There are functions that are continuous precisely on countable sets (e.g. it's not hard to make a function continuous precisely on $\Bbb{Z}$), but you can't have continuity precisely on a countable and dense subset of $\Bbb{R}$ (by Baire category theorem).
